# Log4j JDBCAppender to log stacktraces

Tags: jdbc, log4j, stack-trace

Using `org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender`, how can I get stracktraces logged with `warn` and `error` into the `PatternLayout`.

I'm logging like

```
logger.warn("warning description", e);
logger.error("error description", e);
```

I get the String descriptions into the table, but the Throwable's stacktrace is now where.  Is there another parameter that I can access via the `PatternLayout`. Currently I am using

```
"INSERT INTO app_logs (app, log_date, log_level, location, loc, message) VALUES ('my-apps-name', '%d{ISO8601}','%p', '%C.java', '%C{1}.java:%L', '%m')"
```

into a table

```
TABLE `app_logs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `app` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_level` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `loc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution.

Replace the `PatternLayout` class with the `EnhancedPatternLayout` class.

[`org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html)

You'll also need to include the [apache-log4j-extra dependency](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/download.html)

Or [include it in your pom](http://www.mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/apache-log4j-extras):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>apache-log4j-extras</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You now have access to %throwable

> `%throwable{short}` or `%throwable{1}` will output the first line of stack
>   trace.  `throwable{none}` or `throwable{0}` will suppress the stack trace.
>   `%throwable{n}` will output n lines of stack trace if a positive integer
>   or omit the last -n lines if a negative integer.

I added to my table,

```
TABLE `app_logs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `app` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_date` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_level` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `loc` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text,
  `throwable` text,
  `stacktrace` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

And updated my pattern to populate these columns.

```
"INSERT INTO app_logs (app, log_date, log_level, location, loc, message, throwable, stacktrace) VALUES ('my-apps-name', '%d{ISO8601}','%p', '%C.java', '%C{1}.java:%L', '%m', '%throwable{short}', '%throwable{100}')"
```

Comment: This solution works fine but then the stack trace may have commas or single-quotes and we have to sanitize the data for which you should override getLogStatement func as shown by Sangeet Kumar in here in one of his answers.

Comment: I am aware this an old post. Wanted to point out that the link in the answer is broken. Could you please update the link for the benefit of those (like me) who are interested in this solution.

Comment: I cannot download log4j-extra dependecy from maven

Answer (score 3):

Solution is we need to use EnhancedPattern Layout, by using this we can log the entire stack trace into DB. But there is one issue if we use this if the Stacktrace contain comma(,) , the message will not be get logged.I have solve this by over writing getLogStatement() which is available in JDBC appender Sourcecode

Follow the following steps

1. Download [Log4j1.2.17](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html).
   Enhanced patternlayout is available from log41.2.16 ver
2. Edit log4j properties file

   ```
   log4j.rootLogger = WARN, DB
   log4j.appender.DB=abc.xyz.MyJdbcAppender
   log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/DBNAME
   log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
   log4j.appender.DB.user=user_name
   log4j.appender.DB.password=password
   log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
   log4j.appender.DB.conversionPattern=Insert into MylogFile(logid,loglevel,logcriteria,message,stacktrace,date) values (mysequence.nextval,’%p’,’%c’,
   ‘%m’,’%throwable{40},’%d{ABSOLUTE}’)
   ```
3. Now create a new class that will extend JDBCappender and overwrite `getLogStatement()`:

   ```
   Public MyJdbcAppender extends JDBCAppender{
   protected String getLogStatement(LoggingEvent event) {
   if(null!=event.getThrowableInformation() && event.getThrowableInformation().getThrowable() instance of SQLException){
   SQLException myexce= new SQLException(event.
   getThrowableInformation().getThrowable().getMessage().
   replaceAll(“’”,” “),event.getThrowableInformation().getThrowable());
     LoggingEvent clone = new LoggingEvent(
       event.fqnOfCategoryClass,
       LogManager.getLogger(event.getLoggerName()),
       event.getLevel(),
   event.getLevel(),event.getMessage(),myexce); 
    return getLayout().format(clone);
   }
   return getLayout().format(event)
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: @SangeetKumar you'll also find you need to escape `'`

Answer (score 3):

To extend on MikeNereson's answer, here is a log4j.properties that worked:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,DB
log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://server/db
log4j.appender.DB.user=user
log4j.appender.DB.password=pwd
log4j.appender.DB.layout.ConversionPattern=INSERT INTO app_logs (app, log_date, log_level, location, loc, message, throwable, stacktrace) VALUES ('appname', '%d{ISO8601}','%p', '%C.java', '%C{1}.java:%L', '%m', '%throwable{short}', '%throwable{100}')
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.category.ke.co=ERROR
log4j.category.ke.co.appender-ref=DB
```

Comment: setting log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout produces a ClassCastException org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout cannot be cast to org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

Comment: check your Log4j version.  Download Log4j1.2.17+

Answer (score 2):

log4j 1.2.16+ 's EnhancedPatternLayout is not work! because it extends org.apache.log4j.Layout rather than org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout, but in JDBCAppender:

```
public void setSql(String s) {
    sqlStatement = s;
    if (getLayout() == null) {
        this.setLayout(new PatternLayout(s));
    }
    else {
        ((PatternLayout)getLayout()).setConversionPattern(s);  //Point1
    }
}
```

So if you use JDBCAppender like this:

```
log4j.appender.JDBC=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender    
log4j.appender.JDBC.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
log4j.appender.JDBC.sql=INSERT INTO email_send_error(insert_date, level, location, message, stacktrace) VALUES (now(), '%p', '%C,%L', '%m', '%throwable{short}')
```

will throw a ClassCastException in Point1:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout cannot be cast to org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>       at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.setSql(JDBCAppender.java:330)

**EDIT (after in-depth research):**
Use *log4j.appender.JDBC.layout.ConversionPattern* instead of *log4j.appender.JDBC.sql*, will avoid above ClassCastException:

```
 log4j.appender.JDBC.layout.ConversionPattern=INSERT INTO email_send_error(insert_date, level, location, message, stacktrace) VALUES (now(), '%p', '%C,%L', '%m', '%throwable{short}')
```

and don't forget record the throwed exception to logger:

```
logger.error(String errorMsg, Throwabe e); // Dont forget e
```

Comment: Just to say that if your solution runs on log4j 1.2.16, on 1.2.17 it doesn't run...