# log4j JDBCAppender java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, jdbc, log4j

I have a simple sample of log4j:

Test.java:

```
package com.mobin.pack1;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Test {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Test.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         try {
         int x = 0;
            int y = 5;
            int z = y/x;

            System.out.println(z);

         } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("error" , e);
         }      
    }
}
```

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, DB
log4j.appender.DB=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.DB.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/logDB
log4j.appender.DB.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
log4j.appender.DB.user=root
log4j.appender.DB.password=123
log4j.appender.DB.sql=INSERT INTO TestLOGS(DATE,LOGGER,LEVEL,MESSAGE,THROWABLE) VALUES('%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}','%C:%L','%p','%m','%throwable{100}')
log4j.appender.DB.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
```

dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

TestLOGS table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `TestLOGS` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DATE` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `LOGGER` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `LEVEL` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `MESSAGE` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `THROWABLE` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

when i run it i get this exceptions:

```
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [sql] to value "INSERT INTO TestLOGS(DATE,LOGGER,LEVEL,MESSAGE,THROWABLE) VALUES('%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}','%C:%L','%p','%m','%throwable{100}')". 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout cannot be cast to org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.setSql(JDBCAppender.java:330)
.
.
.
log4j:ERROR Failed to excute sql
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'error' at line 1
```

but when i change "org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout" to org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout in log4j.properties i don't get these exceptions but in THROWABLE column of table inserted value "mainhrowable{100}".

what is problem?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734044/log4j-jdbcappender-to-log-stacktraces

Comment: I have Written this sample from that post . but my problem is something else that explain in my post.

Comment: That post suggested adding a dependency that I don't think you added, apache-log4j-extras

Comment: I add that dependency but i have exception again

Answer (score 0):

If you see the [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/org/apache/log4j/jdbc/JDBCAppender.java#JDBCAppender.setSql%28java.lang.String%29) of `org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender`, you will notice in the method `setSql` that an instance of `org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout` is required. So the error you get is *correct*.

Basically, you have two options:

- Modify your SQL statement and use `org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout`.
- Extend the class `org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender` and override the method `setSql`. Add it to your configuration.